# Differentiating kids' party and adults' party

Tags: word-request

In my native language (portuguese) we can easily differentiate a party for kids and for adults through the word we use for party.

When I say **adults' party**, I mean a party with a DJ where young people party all night long, men hit on girls (and vice versa), get drunk etc:

[image]

and **kids party**, I mean a nice cake and sing happy birthday to you.

So, are there any words to refer to **kids' parties** and **adults' parties** that are not shared between these two kinds?

Comment: What are the two words (or phrases) in Portuguese?

Comment: You can say *festinha de aniversário* for kids' party and *balada* for adults' party.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some words that we use in English for events:

**Party**

Any social gathering, usually with invites.

**Birthday party**

This is typically used to refer to a child's party and is rarely used to refer to an adult's birthday. It can still be used however.

**"do"**

A "do", such as a birthday "do" is a more mature way to refer to an event. Is is more civilised and would perhaps refer to a "wedding do" or similar.

**Clubbing**

To "go out clubbing" is when you go to a night club.

**Sesh**

A "sesh" is an informal word used by teenagers at the moment, to refer to any party where people are expecting to get drunk. You would not use it in a formal setting and I've never heard anyone over the age of 18 say it.

**Celebration**

This is another more mature and formal name for a dinner or social event.

**Disco**

The word "disco" is rarely used, from my experience. The most common use of it that I've come across these days is a "school disco", which involves music, snacks, and lots of hyper kids running round a sports hall. The original meaning of "disco" from the 60s and onward is rarely used.

**Summary**

There is no explicit word for a "party for adults with loud music and getting drunk". I think the closest you'll get is using "Birthday party" for a kids' party, and using the word "Party" in context so that it is obvious you mean an adults' party.